# Handle CoreData not in RootViewController(migration of vanilla coredata-project)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, core-data-migration

First, I'm really new to CoreData.

Now I've created a vanilla CoreData-project and have copied all the code to my project in which I want to implement CoreData.

In the CoreData-vanilla project, the first viewcontroller(MasterViewController), is the controller who handles the managedObjectContext:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    BilderViewController *controller = (BilderViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    return YES;
}
```

But I want my second ViewController, to handle CoreData:

[image]

As you see here, I want the "Bilder"-Viewcontroller to handle/use Core Data. Every method is in that controller, so it should work. I've already tried to change the method to:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    BilderViewController *controller = [[BilderViewController alloc] init];
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    return YES;
}
```

But than, I receive the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a
>   legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name
>   'Event''

My managedObjectContext-method:

```
// Returns the managed object context for the application.
// If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Btw: Eventually, somebody also knows, why the prototype-cell isn't at the top of my tableview. Thx.

Comment: I suspect you're just passing nil around for the managed object context. Does your app delegate initialize the Core Data stack? That's how the context gets a value.

Comment: I've edited my question and added the managedObjectContext method

Answer (score 0):

In your `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` while using storyboards, you don't need to alloc-init the view controller. The view controller you are setting the context for is not the actual one being displayed as this is instantiated by the storyboard

To get this view controller that is instantiated from the storyboard, you can do:

```
UINavigationController *navController = self.window.rootViewController;
MasterViewController *viewController = navController.topViewController;
```

Then you could set the context by:

```
viewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

To set a property on the second view controller, do it in `prepareForSegue:` of the first view controller and get the `segue.destinationViewController` property will be your second view controller and then you can set a managedObjectContext property of that view controller from there

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. I've simply changed the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method to:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}
```

Than, I've simply called my AppDelegate-variable `managedObjectContext` in the Viewcontroller, in whom I've needed it:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

.

```
AppDelegate * appdelegate =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = appdelegate.managedObjectContext;
```